# Ajax data not loading in combobox

Tags: extjs

I have use combobox component in extjs application. I would like to load list through json. But when i click on combobox the list is not shown. Please help me in this.

Following is the ajax call:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
                            url: 'data/vgroup.json',
                            method: 'Get',
                            timeout: 9000,
                            success: function(response, opts) {
                                var device = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                                var device_records = new Array();

                                for(var itr=0; itr < device.vgroup.length; itr++) {
                                    var record = new Array();
                                    record[0] = device.vgroup[itr].name;
                                    //alert(device.vgroup[itr].name);
                                    device_records[itr] = record;
                                }

                                vgfrmextension_device = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
                                    fields: ['name'],
                                    data : device_records
                                });
                            },
                            failure: function(response, opts) {
                                Ext.MessageBox.alert('Failure', "Link not found");
                            }
                        });
```

Following is the component:

```
{
            xtype:'combobox',
            fieldLabel: 'Team name* ',
            editable:false,
            /*allowBlank: false,*/
            store: vgfrmextension_device,
            valueField:'name',
            displayField:'name',
            name: 'txtMode',
            id:'txtModeId',
            queryMode: 'local',
            triggerAction: 'all',
            emptyText:'Select Mode',    
            listeners: {

            }
        },
```

here is the json:

```
{
    vgroup: [
        {
            'id': 'team1',
            'name': '100G',
            'size': '5646546546',
            'available': '545644541',
            'player': 'avi',
            'status': 'Good'
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do the loading through the store. Here's an example from an old app of mine:

```
FC.Global.Toolbar = [{
    xtype: 'combo',
    store: new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy(new Ext.data.Connection({
            url: 'comboboxlist.php'
        })),
        root: 'items',
        fields: ['name']
    }),
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'name',
    mode: 'local',
    triggerAction: 'all',
    typeAhead: true,
    minChars: 1,
    id: 'widgetloadcombobox',
    listeners: {render: function(e) {this.getStore().load();}}
},{
    // Other toolbar items
}]
```

And here's what the JSON returned by the HttpProxy call looks like (with only a single item):

```
{"items":[{"name":"Generator"}]}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am using json to call the list items, not the php. It would be really great if you could provide the detail answer in MVC structure.I am using Extjs4

Comment: I would imagine you just need to change proxy connection. Change the proxy url to read 'data/vgroup.json' and the root to 'vgroup'.

Comment: @Hemant PHP is not a data exchange format, but a server-side programming language that can - besides others - [produce JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). Whether you load your data from a JSON file or from a PHP-generated "JSON file" doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

may be you should first check the device_records array.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
                            url: 'data/vgroup.json',
                            method: 'Get',
                            timeout: 9000,
                            success: function(response, opts) {
                                var device = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                                var device_records = [
                                         {"name":"John"},
                                         {"name":"Anna"},
                                         {"name":"Peter"}
                               ];
                                vgfrmextension_device = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
                                    fields: ['name'],
                                    data : device_records
                                });
                            },
                            failure: function(response, opts) {
                                Ext.MessageBox.alert('Failure', "Link not found");
                            }
                        });
```

if this works, you can change your filling strategy like this:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
                            url: 'data/vgroup.json',
                            method: 'Get',
                            timeout: 9000,
                            success: function(response, opts) {
                                var device = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                                var device_records = [];

                                for(var itr=0; itr < device.vgroup.length; itr++) {
                                    device_records.push(
                                              {
                                               "name": device.vgroup[itr].name
                                            });
                                }

                                vgfrmextension_device = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
                                    fields: ['name'],
                                    data : device_records
                                });
                            },
                            failure: function(response, opts) {
                                Ext.MessageBox.alert('Failure', "Link not found");
                            }
                        });
```

regards.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is mainly that you are making an Ajax call, which is **asynchronous**, and create a NEW store in it, which is set into the `vgfrmextension_device` variable.

And that you use the *same* variable as the store in the combobox - but BEFORE the asynchronous call has completed. So effectively you tell the combobox: Your store is `undefined`, and then you create a store, but that store is never attached to the combobox.

You should create the ArrayStore BEFORE you make the component AND BEFORE you start the request, and load the data into the EXISTING store when it is returned:

```
var vgfrmextension_device = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
    fields: ['name']
});
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'data/vgroup.json',
    method: 'Get',
    timeout: 9000,
    success: function(response, opts) {
        var device = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
        var device_records = new Array();
        for(var itr=0; itr < device.vgroup.length; itr++) {
            var record = new Array();
            record[0] = device.vgroup[itr].name;
            //alert(device.vgroup[itr].name);
            device_records[itr] = record;
        }
        vgfrmextension_device.setData(device_records);
```

**Alternatively**, you can attach the store to the combobox in the `success` method:

```
vgfrmextension_device = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
    fields: ['name'],
    data : device_records
});
Ext.getCmp("widgetloadcombobox").setStore(vgfrmextension_device);
```